# Type of k strange in Lehmann's Analytical geometry book

Tags: math-mode, texworks, typewriter

How can I enter this 'K' in LaTeX?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  What about that k do you find strange?  This is similar to how TeX would typeset `de $k$ para`, although it looks to be a different math font.  Are you trying to figure out that math font?  Or are you wondering why the k is italicized when the surroundings aren't?  Or something else?

Comment: There is no special meaning of the letter; it's just how the italic *k* appears in the font.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this italic `k`?

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other document class
\usepackage{fouriernc}  % choose a suitable font family
 
\begin{document}
r de $k$ para k 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa You're righy. I had a fragment of code into a old document and I have not delete all. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of simplifying your code along the lines suggested by @campa. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico I'm solving in MSE community a series :-) Thank you very much for your edit.